# Access AssetManager from a Non-Activity Class

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, xamarin, android-assets

i am trying to learning `Xamarin` and while i'm at it, i'm also learning `SQLite`. Though i am currently struggling on how i can export the `SampleDb.db` i have in my `Assets` Folder to somewhere (like `Personal Folder` inside) of Android File System.

My problem is that i can't seem to get an access to `AssetManager` on a separate class.

i've tried extending my class to `BaseControl : Activity` and/or `BaseControl : MainActivity` and this is what happens

[image]

i also tried to add a reference to `Android.Content.Res` via `using Android.Content.Res` and intantiating `AssetManager` and this is what happens

[image]

while it is true that i can use this `void method` if i place it in the `MainActivity` Class, i don't want to do such a thing because i'd want this to be separated.

hoping i can pick some tips and tricks here. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since after posting this question, i continued to search for a solution on the entire web. another user posted the same problem as i have on a different website but it turns out that the his approach (his approach didn't worked for him, i don't know why) worked for me.

so what i did was, change the `Assets.Open(DbFile)` to  `Application.Context.Assets.Open(DbFile)` and it worked. well, i haven't tested it yet but the app didn't throw me any kind of exception and as i traced the flow via breakpoint, things went smoothly